# Where can I find some typical nonlinear optical materials SHG working region?

Tags: non-linear-optics

Some example materials are KDP, LiNbO$_3$ and BaTiO$_3$. Where to find their SHG working region? Like some of them perfroming their SHG best in red light region.

I've looked dozens of papers but cannot find any useful information for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start for such searches is companies that sell optical components. They often help people choose the right components, and that often means understanding the components.

For almost any question about optical components, a good place to start is the [RP Photonics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html). For example, you might be interested in the articles on [Frequency Doubling](https://www.rp-photonics.com/frequency_doubling.html), [Nonlinear Crystal Materials](https://www.rp-photonics.com/nonlinear_crystal_materials.html). [Effective Nonlinear Coefficient](https://www.rp-photonics.com/effective_nonlinear_coefficient.html), and so on.

I didn't find anything specific about properties of individual materials in the encyclopedia. So I looked in the Buyer's Guide. For example, [Where to Buy Nonlinear Crystal Materials](https://www.rp-photonics.com/bg/buy_nonlinear_crystal_materials.html). After checking a few vendor sites, I found a [Nonlinear Crystals](http://www.laserton.com/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=lists&catid=36) page from Laserton, which leads to their [NLO Crystal Overview](http://laserton.com/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=show&catid=36&id=163) page. You might find what you are looking for there. Or browse some more.

Comment: Thank you very much. The information you provided is very useful.